# React native : how to share a websocket between components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobile, react-native

I want to use data recived from websocket in my components :
also  how  I can  share a websocket connection and data between components ?

Comment: Did you try writing code for same? Do you have some related code that you can show us? Does this help? [Reactjs: how to share a websocket between components](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36120119/2873538)

Comment: no i try that but no result